# Get rid of .Select?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way that I can get rid of .Select in the following code?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AI$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
Range("C3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "00"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AI$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: downvoted, because you did not research this before posting your question

Comment: A question that covers lots of things on this matter: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/7690982). **EDIT**: Didn't see, but @SeanC already refered to this link.

Answer (score 5):

sure:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AI$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
Range(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "00"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AI$5000").AutoFilter Field:=3
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for more details

Comment: @CC268, such an easy question no doubt has tons of resources dedicated to it on the internet. The best way to learn is not to get other people to give you the answers.